# Square root of a $2\times 2$ matrix with $Det(A)=Tr(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Does there exist a matrix $A_{2\times 2}$ with real entries which has a square root and $Det(A)=Tr(A)=0$ ?

Let A be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with real entries, then a square root of the matrix is given by $$M = \frac{1}{t}(A+sI)$$ where $s^2 = det(A)$ and $t^2 = Tr(A)+2s$ (Square root can have complex entries). This follows, as $M^2 = \frac{1}{t^2}(A^2+2sA+s^2I) $ $= A + \frac{1}{t^2}(A^2-Tr(A)A+det(A)I) = A$. However, can we find a square root of $A$ if $t=0$ ? If $t=0$, that would imply both $Tr(A)-2\sqrt{Det(A)}$ and $Tr(A)+2\sqrt{Det(A)}$ are zero. Which implies $Det(A)=0$ and $Tr(A)=0$. I couldn't find such an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
X^2-0X+0
$$
Show that if $B$ is a square root of $A$, then the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $X^2$.
But then
$$
A=B^2=0
$$

Comment: Thank you! $Det(B^2) = 2Det(B) = Det(A) = 0$ and $Tr(B^2) = Tr(B)^2 - 2Det(B) $ $= Tr(B)^2 = Tr(A) = 0$. Therefore characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $X^2$ !

Comment: @Sabhrant Or: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and hence $\lambda^2=0$.